# how to use the maximum likelihood function to acquire the maximum likelihood (ML) estimate

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

I'm reading this book [Tracking and Data Association](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120797607). The author gives an example for estimating an unknown non-random variable $x$ given some observations $z_{j}$ corrupted by Gaussian noise $ w \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2})$ as follows

$$
z = x + w
$$

The maximum likelihood function then is 
$$
\Lambda(x) = p(z|x) = \mathcal{N}(z; x, \sigma^{2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} exp \left(\frac{(z-x)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right)
$$

Now the goal is to acquire $\hat{x}^{ML}$ which is

$$
\hat{x}^{ML}(j) \triangleq  \arg\max_x \ p(z_{j} | x )
$$

In Matlab, the following code is to generate $z_{j}$

```
clear all
clc

x = 1;
sigma = 0.5;
for i = 1:5
    z(i) = x + sigma*randn();
end
```

The observations are

```
1.7192    1.1626    0.6225    1.6851    0.1442
```

The problem is now how I can calculate $\Lambda(x)$ since $x$ is unknown? In the book, the example is for one observation and it is evident that $\hat{x}^{ML} = z_{1}$. Should I start from this value to calculate the rest of  $\Lambda(x)$?

Comment: Are you looking to do this computationally, or are you also open to doing it by hand? To get $argmax_x p(z|x)$ you could take $log( p(z|x) )$ ($log$ is a monotonic function so the argmax is left unchanged) and then find where its derivative is zero to get the max.

Comment: @eigenchris, I'm sorry but I didn't get it. The problem is how can I get $p(z|x)$. $x$ is unknown. I definitely can use the average but I'm curious how The maximum likelihood function is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by hand if you know these basic facts:

- the $\arg\max_x \Lambda(x)$ is located at the $x$ that solves $\frac{d}{dx}\Lambda(x)=0$
- the $\arg\max_x \Lambda(x)$ is unaffected by the $log$ function; $argmax_x \Lambda(x) = argmax_x log( \Lambda(x) )$
- if $z$ is a collection of *independent* samples $z_1, z_2, ... z_n$, then their joint probability is the product of the marginal distributions: $p(z|x)=p(z_1, z_2, ... z_n|x) = \prod_j p(z_j|x)$
- the $log$ of a product is the sum of $log$'s: $log(\prod_j p(z_j|x))=\sum_j log(p(z_j|x))$

Now we can derive an equation for $\hat{x}^{ML}$.

$$log( p(z|x) ) = log(\prod_j p(z_j|x) ) = \sum_j log(p(z_j|x)) $$

$$= \sum_j log( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}) + \sum_j log( exp \left(\frac{(z_j-x)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right) )$$

$$= \sum_j log( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}) + \sum_j \left(\frac{(z_j-x)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right) $$

$$\arg\max_x p(z|x) = \arg\max_x log( p(z|x) ) = \arg\max_x \left[ \sum_j log( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma}) + \sum_j \left(\frac{(z_j-x)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right) \right]$$

$$\arg\max_x p(z|x) = \arg\max_x \left[  \sum_j \left(\frac{(z_j-x)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right) \right]$$

$$0 = \frac{d}{dx} \left[  \sum_j \left(\frac{(z_j-x)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} \right) \right]$$

$$0 = \sum_j \frac{-2(z_j-x)}{2\sigma^{2}} $$

$$0 = \sum_j^n -z_j + \sum_j^n x $$

$$\hat{x}^{ML} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_j^n z_j $$

So the maximum likelihood estimator is just the average of the measurements in this case.